Looking for term for logical fallacy of answering two distinctive questions at once
Please help me finding the proper name for the following logical fallacy: one fuses together two distinctive questions into single one pretending the latter should be answered «Yes/no».
I read through this list of fallacies, but failed to find the answer (that being said, I might have overlooked it because the list is quite extensive).

The fallacy of many questions (plurimum interrogationum) "consists in demanding or giving a single answer to a question when this answer could either be divided (example: “Do you like the twins?” “Neither yes nor no; but Ann yes and Mary no.”) or refused altogether"

@Conifold I believe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barreled_question is a bit more to the point. Still your comment answers it as well. Thank you! If you wish to convert to an answer, I'll be delighted to accept it.

It is, indeed, closer. You are allowed (and encouraged) to post self-answers here, you can even accept them after 48 hours.

In situations where the fallacy lies more on the person answering than on the one asking (or with no one "asking" per se), could it be conflation?

"Would you be a nice guy and lend me five bucks?"
